# Ubuntu detects a crash for a program I never run

Tags: package-management, apport, top

I use `atop` to get a few basic things above `top` without being too fancy. I've used it on many systems and I'm aware that sometimes when it first runs it can print out "Floating Point Exception" and exit.

The part I don't understand is why after a basic `apt-get install atop` two things happen:

- Ubuntu throws up a dialog explaining it wants to report an error, clicking more details reveals it's the floating point exception for `atop`
- Upon startup we get the same error again

I can understand that if I actually run the program it could encounter an error, but how is it encountering errors immediately upon installation (ones that would indicate it's being ran for some reason?) and why is `atop` being ran at startup on it's own to display those errors after boot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**When `atop` is installed, it also installs a system service that keeps running it in the background.** The service is started every time the computer is started.

In addition, packages can have (and often have) scripts that are automatically run before installation, after installation, before removal, and after removal.

In the case of `atop`, there is a post-install script (`/var/lib/dpkg/info/atop.postinst`) that runs `invoke-rc.d atop start`. This is pretty typical on Debian-based systems: when you install a service, it gets automatically started.

So, what is does this `atop` service do? Reading `/etc/init.d/atop`, it ends up running the following (where `$CURDAY` stands for the current day, for example `20161220` at the time of writing):

```
/usr/bin/atop -a -w /var/log/atop/atop_$CURDAY 600
```

According to the man page, this keeps one `atop` command running all the time, writing raw data under `/var/log/atop` every 10 minutes (600 seconds), forever (until the machine is shut down). This allows the user to examine past usage of the system, not just current usage. Have a look at the RAW DATA STORAGE section of the man page.

Now, since `atop` apparently crashes on your machine, you get one crash when the package is installed (and the service is started) and one crash each time the computer is started (because this starts the service). There is also a `cron` job that restarts the service at midnight (so that a new log file is used every day), so you will get one more crash at midnight.

If you only care about running `atop` from the command line, and do not care about the service, you can disable it by running `sudo update-rc.d atop disable`.

Comment: Great answer thank you for going into detail I was not aware it installed a service.